# How to write a plugin for Android Studio?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, android-studio, eclipse-plugin

How I can write a plugin for Android Studio?

I've looked for documentation, but unfortunately there is very little or it's poor, so what articles can recommended?

Can Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA plugin work in Android Studio?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since Android Studio is Based in IntelliJIDEA, a good starting point is the IntelliJ docs:

[Jetbrains Plugin Development](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment)

Comment: So you think that if I develop IntelliJ Idea Plugin it will work in Android Studio?

Comment: Since the actual IntelliJIDEA plugins are already working in android studio, I think so.

Comment: And Eclipse plugin of course will not work in Android Studio?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Android studio as far as I know, has nothing to do with eclipse

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good resource for Plugin Development working within Android Studio compatibility.

http://yvonne.idescout.com/2015/08/writing-plugins-for-android-studio.html