# How to start development of a plugin for Android Studio?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-studio, intellij-plugin

So, I've read: [How to write a plugin for Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713974/how-to-write-a-plugin-for-android-studio) as well as the documentation for writing plugins for IntelliJ (although they seem to be quite out of date), and I'm still a little lost.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to get the following plugin source: https://github.com/winterDroid/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin to compile, so I can make a small addition to it. I've downloaded IntelliJ community edition, and I'm able to compile small IntelliJ plugins if I follow the above documentation, but when I try to compile the source for an Android Studio plugin, it tells me it can't find the import `org.jetbrains.android.facet.AndroidFacet;`

My thinking is that I've probably missed an SDK somewhere, but, for the life of me, I can't determine which additional SDK/library I need to import to get the Android-specific suite of classes.

Could someone guide me in the right direction to get a plugin to build to use Android Studio? If it packages it as a zip file (rather than launching Android Studio with the plugin embedded), that's fine - I can manually copy over my .zip files to my Android Studio installation to test.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add plugins/android/lib/android.jar to the classpath of your IntelliJ IDEA SDK.

Comment: So, this did work to compile it, but for some reason, it doesn't build a jar/zip. If I manually have it build a jar/zip using the `Build Artifacts` configuration (after setting it up), it will install in AS, but it won't actually run (even if I don't change the source). Is there a way you know of to get debugging/log information from AS (or perhaps to run it in a debugger)?

Comment: When do you expect a jar/zip to be built? For a plugin project, you need to invoke the "Prepare plugin module for deployment" action to produce a jar/zip file.