# Running an IntelliJ-developed plugin in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-14, android-studio-plugin

There's another thread [about this topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37035922/run-intellij-plugin-on-android-studio) but with no accepted/sufficient answer. I am building a plugin targeted at Android Studio using IntelliJ Community Edition [plugin development tools](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html) and I need to run and rebug the plugin in Android Studio. However when the run command is clicked in IntelliJ CE, it opens another instance of IntelliJ and opens the plugin in IntelliJ.

How can I change this configuration to run the plugin in Android Studio instead of IntelliJ? Upon researching, Android Studio plugins are developed using IntelliJ if I'm not mistaken (As mentioned [here](https://yalantis.com/blog/android-studio-plugin-development/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713974/how-to-write-a-plugin-for-android-studio)). There's no official guide addressing this. Any clarification and guides on getting this done?

**EDIT**

The duplicate thread does not solve the problem as it does not state a solution to run the plugin in Android Studio

Comment: Is your SDK pointing to AS installation?

Comment: No its pointing to IntelliJ installation as advised by the official plugin development guide @Meo

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run intellij plugin on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37035922/run-intellij-plugin-on-android-studio)

Comment: I literally linked that answer and stated that there's no solution in that thread and none of the suggestions worked in my 1st sentence. Don't mark this as duplicate please @BasLeijdekkers

Comment: It is a duplicate, the answer clearly says "Point the IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK home path to your Android Studio installation." Another option would be choosing different JRE at your run configuration, but why would you do that.

Comment: The OP says it didn't work and it didn't work for me either. Does that mean no one can ask the same question again? @Meo

Comment: As I said, you are doing it wrong. Upload your whole project including project files, or report a bug.